# Pixel 7a and Pixel 8 not can't install my app

Tags: flutter, android-14

I have an app written in flutter a few years ago. It has been updated constantly and in the last period a new version was uploaded to make it available to users with android 14. It was increased targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 34.
I uploaded the new version to google play console, review was done and after approval it was published.
I tried it myself with a samsung galaxy a14 with android 14 and it works correctly.
A few days ago some customers with android 14 claimed that downloading the app would come up with an error popup during installation that say "App not installed". These users had a Pixel 8 and a Pixel 7a.
Some others don't find app on the store.

I then went to the play console and saw that both Pixel 8 and 7a were shown to be supported as per the picture.
Do you have any ideas what could be causing the problem?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "would come up with an error popup" it would be useful to know what the error actually was.

Comment: Popup say "App not installed" after update